# Чтение из файла построчно и запись в массив

Tags: python

Как открыть, прочитать файл построчно и записать строки из файла с массив?

Comment: хммм... странно вы [ищете](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+file+into+list&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=read+file+into+list+in+python)...

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
with open("file.ext") as file:
    array = [row.strip() for row in file]
```

Выражение [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) обеспечит закрытие файла после окончания работы. Выражение, создающее `array` называется генератором списков ([list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)). Внутри него перебираются строки, оно равносильно:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    # blah-blah
```

Ну а метод [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) удаляет с конца и начала строки лишние пробелы, в том числе символ окончания строки. В случае, если нет необходимости обрезать пробельные символы в начале строки, можно использовать [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.rstrip)

Comment: Т.к. автор про окончания строк ничего не писал, то можно было просто написать `array = file.readlines()`.

Comment: @insolor, не написал, но если у вопрошающего возникают подобные вопросы, то можно поиграть в телепата и обрезать конец строки - это типичное поведение при чтении _текстового_ файла.

Comment: array = list(open('text.txt'))
или так